# Google maps, pass map to function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to move to the first market put in the map, but i can't make it work.

First, I store the marker in one array, at this point I only need to the first, later I will create the entire logic.

here is the code:

```
 var geocoder;
   var map;
   var markersArray = [];

 //Initialization
 function initMap() {

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 16,
     center: {lat: 14.601313, lng: -90.519114},
   });

   map.addListener('click', function(e) {
     placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
   });

 }

 //Add marker function
 function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latLng,
     map: map
   });
    markersArray.push(latLng);
    map.panTo(latLng);
 }

 //Button: click move to the very first marker
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#MyButton').click(function(){
 alert("click");
       alert(markersArray[0].lat());
       map.panTo(markersArray[0].lat(),markersArray[0].lng());
     });
   });
```

Fix:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#MyButton').click(function(){
       if (markersArray.length > 0){

         map.setCenter(markersArray[0]);
     }
       //map.fitBounds(markersArray[0].lat(),markersArray[0].lng());
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map variable is local to the initialize function (at least the one that contains the actual map).  The global map variable is never intialized.

Change:

```
var map;
//Initialization
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
```

To:

```
var map;
//Initialization
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85dt6rha/1/)

Comment: In your example, the map is not center to the first marker, that's what I need, also thanks for the advise. When I create many markers across the map, the button must move the map to the first  marker, in screen center.

Comment: You have an error in your code.  The `map.panTo()` function takes a google.maps.LatLng as an argument, not two numbers.

Comment: I trie several ways, but with no luck. with the array inself , give this format, (12.32323,-13.0099877), i try with this value, split the value, and I can't make it work.